# Not able to connect to mobile broadband

Tags: 12.04, networking, mobile-broadband

I can connect to internet by modem, when i plug the device before booting.After unplugging and when try to re plug the modem after log in,there is no enable mobile network option and i cannot connect to the internet.Can anyone help me ?....

Comment: how can you connect before booting?

Comment: connecting the modem to the computer,not to the internet

Comment: What modem do you use?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd classify this one as "too localised"  when it affects anyone doing a 12.04 LTS install and relying on wireless broadband and network manager.  Possibly, you'd say it was off-topic because it's a bug, except the work-arounds might actually help someone and I'd still argue it should be left available since it's not obviously a bug.

Comment: @fabricator4 It's still available. There's no restriction on searching/viewing closed questions. It's answered so it won't be deleted automatically. Even manual deletion would need more votes than usual, as the total question+answer score here is 5 (and anyone who thinks this is valuable can upvote). I think, to the extent to which this is not too localized, it's OT as a bug. Workarounds belong in the bug, where they can stay up to date and help all the other people there. It's linked here, so anyone here can get to it. However, if you think we should reopen, you may want to post on meta.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of a bug in Network Manager 0.9.4.0 that prevents it from detecting the 3G modem all of the time.  I had this intermittent problem with the built-in Huawei modem in my EeePC.  The problem seems to have been resolved with Network manager 0.9.6.0 which ships with 12.10.

You should try restarting Network Manager in the first instance.  In a terminal:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

and see if that enables the 3G modem when you insert after booting.

Consider upgrading to 12.10, installing Network Manager 0.9.6.0 (into 12.04 LTS), or wait until the later Network Manager 0.9.6.0 is upgraded in 12.04 LTS.  Version upgrades can take a while to be incorporated into previous releases, even (or especially) LTS ones.  I believe this will happen, but it probably won't be until [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/880084) is also fixed to everyone's satisfaction.

3G has been a rocky road since 11.04, I'm afraid.  As stated in that bug, you will have to enable Wireless broadband again after every boot or resume.  There's a nice work-around that works for a clean boot however.